# "Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs" error for custom function

Tags: matlab

i'm currently trying to implement a  custom class (intL) that handles large integers operations by using vectors.
In this class one function is make_intL, which is supposed to take as an input a regular integer array and outputs an array of intL objects of the same size.
Everytime i call this function, i get "Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs for function make_intL", which i've never seen before.
The function:

```
function intL_array = make_intL(array)
            [rows,cols] = size(array);
            intL_array = intL.empty(0,0);
            intL_array(rows,cols) = intL();
            for i = 1:rows
                for j = 1:cols
                    intL_array(i,j) = intL(array(i,j));
                end
            end
        end
```

The error message doesn't specify a line so i don't really know where to look to try and debug, and looking at the already asked topics didn't help either.

Calls i've tried:

```
intL_array = make_intL([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
intL_array = make_intL([123;456])
intL_array = make_intL([1 2 3 ; 4 5 6])
```

I also tried using varargin + nargin so that no matter the input, it would work, but still getting the same error.
I'd be very happy if someone had an explanation as to why this happens.

Comment: You say you're implementing a class (which would typically have the object itself as the first input of contained functions) but you've only shown a function. Is that function standalone or part of a class? Please post the full verbatim error message which MATLAB shows, it will have a stack trace including line numbers. Is this definitely the version of `make_intL` which is being called? Check by running `which make_intL -all` in the command window to ensure there's not others higher on your path